# NoMessageBodyWriterFoundFailure: Could not find MessageBodyWriter

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, glassfish, jersey, jax-rs

When I develop the **Jax-rs**  web service I use Viewable then I got like this error,

**org.jboss.resteasy.core.NoMessageBodyWriterFoundFailure: Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.Viewable of media type: application/octet-stream**

THis is my web.xml,

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>FunkyApp</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/spring-hibernate-resteasy.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/resteasy</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- <filter>
        <filter-name>jersey-serlvet</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>obl.funkey.service</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.feature.Redirect</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.JSPTemplatesBasePath</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/pages</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.WebPageContentRegex</param-name>
            <param-value>/(css|js|img|resources|(WEB-INF/pages))/.*</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>jersey-serlvet</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping> -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/resteasy/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

When I add comment filed project run in server but can't get any output,

this is my java code,

```java
@GET
@Path("getusers")
public Response index(@Context HttpServletRequest request,@Context HttpServletResponse response){
    request.setAttribute("key", "value");
        return Response.ok(new Viewable("/vxml/E_welcome", null)).build();
}
```

I got like this error,

```
Stacktrace:
2015-09-09 00:57:50,872 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] WARN  org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler  - Failed executing GET /funkeyservice/getusers
org.jboss.resteasy.core.NoMessageBodyWriterFoundFailure: Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.Viewable of media type: application/octet-stream
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.writeNomapResponse(ServerResponseWriter.java:67)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:427)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:376)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:179)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

How I solve this, Is this error because glassfish and jboss two server?

Thanks.

Comment: Your first problem is trying to mix RESTeasy and Jersey. I've come across a few of your posts which I just chose to completely ignore because the information you provide is just a complete mess in terms of implementation (especially with the mixing of Jersey and RESTeasy). I suggest you decide which implementation you want to go with and check out a good tutorial on just _that_ implementation. Clean up your project to have only jars/dependencies and configurations from only _that_ specific implementation. As for this question, RESTeasy doesn't support `Viewable`. Thats a Jersey specific class.

Comment: Thanks.. I try this.

Comment: How to forward from a JAX-RS service to JSP in RESTeasy(without Viewable) ?

Comment: You can use [`return Response.seeOther(url).build()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#seeOther-java.net.URI-) to redirect the client to page. You will need to add any data to query parameters on the redirect url. But with your current code, I don't see any need to redirect. Usually redirect is used for POST. If you want to make a GET, why not just request the jsp page directly?